# Q: save Open Text Exceed windows sizes and positions?

Tags: exceed

how do you save your last windows sizes and position when using Exceed? I'm using it to run SAS environment but every time I boot it up, windows are always going back to default sizes and positions :(

Comment: Are you asking how to set default sizes and positions of windows in SAS's Display Manager application?  The program editor, log, output windows?  If so try the wsave display manager command.

Comment: Hi Tom,

jwu, will look into this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this useful user written paper on [using Display Manager](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/151-2012.pdf).

> The size and position of each of these windows can be adjusted using
> standard mouse/window techniques. Once they have been adjusted the way
> you want them, use the **WSAVE ALL** command in the command box to save
> these settings for your next SAS session.

Also watch out for issues with not having access to your SASUSER library which can occur when you are running multiple SAS jobs at the same time.  You can prevent the SASUSER library from not being accessed by all of the jobs if you run using the `-RSASUSER` option.  But then you will not be able to run the WSAVE command.  So if you want to make changes to the window locations do it when you do have write access to SASUSER.

Comment: Hi @Tom, read the paper and it was helpful! However, whenever I open my SAS in the logs it says "Unable to open SASUSER.REGSTRY" -- So, the settings will not be saved. :(

Comment: That was the point of my second comment.  The window positions are stored in your SASUSER libary.  If you do not have access then obviously SAS will not know the values.  Sometimes the file it stores that in gets corrupted.  If you are only running one SAS session and it still fails then move the registry information out of the way.  So from operating system rename the file named `regstry.sas7bitm` in your SASUSER directory.  When you start SAS it should make a new one.

Comment: Thanks Tom! Will contact our SysAd/Infra with this since we are using shared user so I cannot just do that personally.

Comment: After fixing the registry information, WSAVE ALL worked! Thanks Tom. I cant upvote your answer I need reputation pts. Sorry!